# Is there a module equivalent of Python's argparse for node.js?

Tags: node.js, module, command-line-arguments

[argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for python makes it quick and easy to handle command-line input, handling positional arguments, optional arguments, flags, input validation and much more. I've started writing applications in node.js and I'm finding it tedious and time consuming to write all that stuff manually.

Is there a node.js module for handling this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a slew of various command line argument handlers at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-commandline

The one I use in most projects is https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js though I would take a look at all of them to see which one suits your specific needs.

Answer (score 10):

There is one [direct port](https://github.com/nodeca/argparse), conveniently also called argparse.

Comment: Direct port is exactly it, only few use cases separate the python from nodejs version.

Comment: Be sure to look at its bug tracker -- there are a lot of open issues. A few of them have caught me out already.

Answer (score 5):

In 18.3.0 nodejs has landed a core addition `util.parseArgs([config])`

Detailed documentation is available here: https://github.com/pkgjs/parseargs#faqs

Comment: This is the official link for the documentation. https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilparseargsconfig the link you posted there is for the polyfill.

Answer (score 2):

There's [yargs](http://yargs.js.org/), which seems to be pretty complete and well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some simple boilerplate code which allows you to provide named args:

```js
const parse_args = () => {
    const argv = process.argv.slice(2);
    let args = {};
    for (const arg of argv){
        const [key,value] = arg.split("=");
        args[key] = value;
    }
    return args;
}

const main = () => {
    const args = parse_args()
    console.log(args.name);
}
```

Example usage:

```bash
# pass arg name equal to monkey
node arg_test.js name=monkey
# Output
>> monkey
```

You can also add a `Set` of accepted names and throw exception if an invalid name is provided:

```js
const parse_args = (valid_args) => {
    const argv = process.argv.slice(2);
    let args = {};
    let invalid_args = [];
    for (const arg of argv){
        const [key,value] = arg.split("=");
        if(valid_args.has(key)){
            args[key] = value;  
        } else {
            invalid_args.push(key);
        }       
    }
    if(invalid_args.length > 0){
        throw new Exception(`Invalid args ${invalid_args} provided`);
    } 
    return args;
}

const main = () => {
    const valid_args = new Set(["name"])
    const args = parse_args(valid_args)
    console.log(args.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Node 18's `util.parseArgs` library:

```js
import path from 'node:path'
import url from 'node:url'
import util from 'node:util'

const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

// Parse arguments
const {
  values: {
    quiet: quietMode
  },
} = util.parseArgs({
  args: process.argv.slice(2),
  options: {
    quiet: {
      type: 'boolean',
      short: 'q',
    },
  },
})

console.log('Quiet mode:', quietMode); // Usage: node ./script.mjs [-q|--quiet]
```

---

### ArgumentParser wrapper class

I wrote a wrapper that acts very similar to the `argparse` library in Python. Any option that does not actually get passed to the internal `util.parseArgs` is added to a private `Map` and fetched when displaying the help.

**Note:** This is a stripped-down version of Python's `argparse` library, so this is not complete.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-console */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */

import path from 'node:path'
import url from 'node:url'
import util from 'node:util'

const __filename = url.fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

const capitalize = (s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1)

class CaseConverter {
  constructor() {}
  transform(_input) {
    throw new Error('Not implemented')
  }
  toCamelCase(input) {
    const [head, ...rest] = this.transform(input)
    return head + rest.map(capitalize).join('')
  }
  toUpperSnakeCase(input) {
    return this.transform(input)
      .map((s) => s.toUpperCase())
      .join('_')
  }
}

class CamelCaseConverter extends CaseConverter {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  transform(input) {
    return input.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
  }
}

class KebabCaseConverter extends CaseConverter {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
  transform(input) {
    return input.split('-')
  }
}

const camelCaseConv = new CamelCaseConverter()
const kebabCaseConv = new KebabCaseConverter()

class ArgumentParser {
  constructor(options) {
    const opts = { ...ArgumentParser.DEFAULT_OPTIONS, ...options }
    this.prog = opts.prog
    this.usage = opts.usage
    this.description = opts.description
    this.epilog = opts.epilog
    this.arguments = []
    this.helpMap = new Map()
    this.metavarMap = new Map()
  }
  addArgument(...args) {
    if (args.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('No argument supplied')
    }
    let options = {}
    if (typeof args.slice(-1) === 'object') {
      options = args.pop()
    }
    if (args.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('No name or flag argument supplied')
    }
    this.#addInternal(args, options)
  }
  #addInternal(nameOrFlags, options) {
    let longName, shortName
    for (let nameOrFlag of nameOrFlags) {
      if (/^--\w[\w-]+$/.test(nameOrFlag)) {
        longName = kebabCaseConv.toCamelCase(nameOrFlag.replace(/^--/, ''))
      } else if (/^-\w$/.test(nameOrFlag)) {
        shortName = kebabCaseConv.toCamelCase(nameOrFlag.replace(/^-/, ''))
      }
    }
    if (!longName) {
      throw new Error('A long name must be provided')
    }

    if (options.type !== 'boolean') {
      this.metavarMap.set(longName, options.metavar || camelCaseConv.toUpperSnakeCase(longName))
    }

    this.arguments.push({
      long: longName,
      short: shortName,
      default: options.default,
      type: options.type,
    })
    if (options.help) {
      this.helpMap.set(longName, options.help)
    }
  }
  #wrapText(text) {
    return wordWrap(text.trim().replace(/\n/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' '), 80, '\n')
  }
  #getScriptName() {
    return path.basename(process.argv[1])
  }
  #buildHelpMessage(options) {
    let helpMessage = ''

    const flags = Object.entries(options)
      .map(([long, option]) => {
        return [options.short ? `-${option.short}` : `--${long}`, this.metavarMap.get(long)].filter((o) => o).join(' ')
      })
      .join(' ')

    helpMessage += `usage: ${this.prog ?? this.#getScriptName()} [${flags}]\n\n`
    if (this.description) {
      helpMessage += this.#wrapText(this.description) + '\n\n'
    }
    helpMessage += 'options:\n'

    const opts = Object.entries(options).map(([long, option]) => {
      const tokens = [`--${long}`]
      if (option.short) {
        tokens[0] += `, -${option.short}`
      }
      if (option.type) {
        tokens.push(option.type)
      }
      return [tokens.join(' '), this.helpMap.get(long) ?? '']
    })

    const leftPadding = Math.max(...opts.map(([left]) => left.length))

    helpMessage +=
      opts
        .map(([left, right]) => {
          return left.padEnd(leftPadding, ' ') + '  ' + right
        })
        .join('\n') + '\n\n'

    if (this.epilog) {
      helpMessage += this.#wrapText(this.epilog)
    }
    return helpMessage
  }
  parseArgs(args) {
    const options = this.arguments.concat(ArgumentParser.defaultHelpOption()).reduce((opts, argument) => {
      opts[argument.long] = {
        type: argument.type,
        short: argument.short,
        default: argument.default,
      }
      return opts
    }, {})

    const result = util.parseArgs({ args, options })

    if (result.values.help === true) {
      console.log(this.#buildHelpMessage(options))
      process.exit(0)
    }

    return result
  }
}

ArgumentParser.defaultHelpOption = function () {
  return {
    long: 'help',
    short: 'h',
    type: 'boolean',
  }
}

ArgumentParser.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
  prog: null, // The name of the program (default: os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
  usage: null, // The string describing the program usage (default: generated from arguments added to parser)
  description: '', // Text to display before the argument help (by default, no text)
  epilog: '', // Text to display after the argument help (by default, no text)
}

/**
 * Wraps a string at a max character width.
 *
 * If the delimiter is set, the result will be a delimited string; else, the lines as a string array.
 *
 * @param {string} text - Text to be wrapped
 * @param {number} [maxWidth=80] - Maximum characters per line. Default is `80`
 * @param {string | null | undefined} [delimiter=null] - Joins the lines if set. Default is `null`
 * @returns {string | string[]} - The joined lines as a string, or an array
 */
function wordWrap(text, maxWidth = 80, delimiter = null) {
  let lines = [],
    found,
    i
  while (text.length > maxWidth) {
    found = false
    // Inserts new line at first whitespace of the line (right to left)
    for (i = maxWidth - 1; i >= 0 && !found; i--) {
      if (/\s/.test(text.charAt(i))) {
        lines.push(text.slice(0, i))
        text = text.slice(i + 1)
        found = true
      }
    }
    // Inserts new line at maxWidth position, since the word is too long to wrap
    if (!found) {
      lines.push(text.slice(0, maxWidth - 1) + '-') // Hyphenate
      text = text.slice(maxWidth - 1)
    }
  }
  if (text) lines.push(text)
  return delimiter ? lines.join(delimiter) : lines
}
```

#### Usage

```js
const argParser = new ArgumentParser({
  description: `this description
    was indented weird
        but that is okay`,
  epilog: `
      likewise for this epilog whose whitespace will
    be cleaned up and whose words will be wrapped
    across a couple lines`,
})

argParser.addArgument('-p', '--profile', { type: 'string', help: 'environment profile' })
argParser.addArgument('-q', '--quiet', { type: 'boolean', default: false, help: 'silence logging' })

const args = argParser.parseArgs(process.argv.slice(2))
const { values } = args
const { profile, quiet: quietMode } = values

console.log('Profile:', profile)
console.log('Quiet mode:', quietMode) // Usage: node ./script.mjs [-q|--quiet]
```

#### Output

```bash
$ node scripts/quietMode.mjs --help
usage: quietMode.mjs [--profile PROFILE --quiet --help]

this description was indented weird but that is okay

options:
--profile, -p string  environment profile
--quiet, -q boolean   silence logging
--help, -h boolean

likewise for this epilog whose whitespace will be cleaned up and whose words
will be wrapped across a couple lines
```

```bash
$ node scripts/quietMode.mjs -p foo
Profile: foo
Quiet mode: false
```

I wrote my own case conversion strategy for kebab-case, camelCase, and UPPER_SNAKE_CASE (also referred to as SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE), but you could us the [`js-convert-case`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-convert-case) npm module instead.